# How do we redefine the value of standard salesforce lightning token values?

Tags: lightning-web-components, design-tokens

In Experience Cloud it is possible to set custom branding set and set the value for colors, but looks like this is very limited to some colors and fonts.

Is there a way to override some standard or global token in LWC?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a LWR experience template rather than an Aura one, you can use the [--dxp Styling Hooks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/brand_hooks.htm) that look like the best way to go.

For an experience, you can add the styling hook custom properties that apply across the whole site via "Edit Head Markup" adding e.g.:

```
<style>
  :root {
    /** Use --dxp-g to make broad changes **/
    --dxp-g-root: #1a1b1e;
    --dxp-g-root-contrast: #fff;
    --dxp-g-brand: #5eb4ff;
    --dxp-g-brand-contrast: #fff;
    --dxp-g-neutral: #76716b;
    --dxp-g-neutral-contrast: #fff;

    /** Use --sds-c to fine-tune where necessary **/
    --sds-c-button-color-background: peachpuff;
  }
</style>
```

From the docs:

> We recommend using --dxp styling hooks to make general changes across the components in you site. But if the --dxp branding defaults don’t provide exactly what you need, you can use --sds styling hooks to fine-tune the appearance of individual components where necessary.

Comment: thanks, I didn't even know about --dxp hooks